# Matplotlib RectangleSelector keeps saving old values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, computer-vision

I am trying to make a bounding box tool for images. I want the tool to first let me draw bounding box using rectangular selector and then after adjusting the bounding box. If I press 'w' I want my bounding box coordinates to be saved in a python list. This is my code:

```
def line_select_callback(clk, rls):
    global tl_list
    global br_list
    global object_list
    global class_list
    plt.connect('key_press_event', set_class)    
    tx = int(clk.xdata)
    ty = int(clk.ydata)
    bx = int(rls.xdata)
    by = int(rls.ydata)

    plt.connect('key_press_event', lambda event: set_final(event, tx, ty, bx, by))


def toggle_selector(event):
    toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

def set_class(event):
    global clas

    if event.key == '1':
        clas = '0'
        print('class set to 0')
    elif event.key == '2':
        print('class set to 1')
        clas = '1'

def set_final(event, tx, ty, bx, by):
    global object_list
    global class_list

    if event.key == 'w':
        tl_list.append((tx, ty))
        br_list.append((bx, by))
        class_list.append(clas)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Default class set to 0')
    for n, image_file in enumerate(os.scandir(image_folder)):
        img = image_file
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
        image = cv2.imread(image_file.path)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        ax.imshow(image)

        toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback,
                                                drawtype='box', useblit=False,
                                                button=[1], minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                                spancoords='pixels', interactive=True )

        bbox = plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
        key = plt.connect('key_press_event', onkeypress)
        plt.show()
```

The problem is. When I save new bounding boxes, the old boxes also get saved. Let's say I draw 3 boxes on an image. The saved coordinates look like:

> {296,181,417,373,0}  {235,178,447,370,0}  {296,181,417,373,0}  {235,178,447,370,0}  {77,125,207,319,0}  {296,181,417,373,0 }

First box is saved 3 times, second box 2 times and last box 1 time. How to solve this?

Comment: You are using opencv in your program. You should consider using `cv2.selectROI`. This function allows you to select rectangles. I think that is easier to work with.

Comment: [Here](https://www.learnopencv.com/how-to-select-a-bounding-box-roi-in-opencv-cpp-python/) is the example. It explains both, C++ and python examples.

Comment: Thanks @Aditya, i didn't knew about it.

Comment: This is pretty chaotic. Best connect exactly one key press event. Disconnect it when finished.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest . I have fixed it and posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple workaround. When you are done adjusting the bounding box press 'n' to save the current bounding box and proceed to draw new bounding box on same image. When you are done making bounding boxes for an image, press 'q' to load next image. Following code can be modified to make a labeling tool for projects like YOLO.

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import matplotlib.patches as patches

Xs = []
Ys = []
breaker = False
tx=0
ty=0
bx=0
by=0

p_tx=0
p_ty=0
p_bx=0
p_by=0

# constants
image_folder = 'images'

def line_select_callback(clk, rls):
    global tx,ty,bx,by
    tx = int(clk.xdata)
    ty = int(clk.ydata)
    bx = int(rls.xdata)
    by = int(rls.ydata)


def onkeypress(event):
    global tx,ty,bx,by, Xs, Ys, p_tx, p_ty, p_bx, p_by
    if event.key == 'n':            
        if (p_tx != tx) or (p_ty != ty) or (p_bx != bx) or (p_by != by):
            Xs.append((tx, bx))
            Ys.append((ty, by))
            mystr=""
            mystr += " " + str(tx)+","+str(ty)+","+str(bx)+","+str(by)+" "
            print(mystr)
            p_tx=tx
            p_ty=ty
            p_bx=bx
            p_by=by
            plt.close()


def toggle_selector(event):
    toggle_selector.RS.set_active(True)

def break_loop(event):
    global breaker
    if event.key == 'q':
        breaker = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for n, image_file in enumerate(os.scandir(image_folder)):        
        while(True):
            img = image_file
            fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
            image = cv2.imread(image_file.path)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            ax.imshow(image)

            for i in range(len(Xs)):
                tl_x, br_x= Xs[i]
                tl_y , br_y = Ys[i]
                rect = patches.Rectangle((tl_x,tl_y), abs(br_x - tl_x), abs(tl_y - br_y),linewidth=1,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')
                ax.add_patch(rect)

            toggle_selector.RS = RectangleSelector(ax, line_select_callback,
                                                    drawtype='box', useblit=False,
                                                    button=[1], minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                                                    spancoords='pixels', interactive=True)

            bbox = plt.connect('key_press_event', toggle_selector)
            plt.connect('key_press_event', onkeypress)
            loopBreaker = plt.connect('key_press_event', break_loop)
            if breaker:
                break
            plt.show()
```